# Rstudio keyboard shortcut to copy from console to source?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

After years of using this site, I'm finally posting my first question!

In RStudio, I often develop a line of code in the console, and then once satisfied, I copy and paste it into my source code. Since I do this many times a day, I thought it would be great if there were a keyboard shortcut.

I don't see anything for this listed in RStudio's keyboard shortcuts (click on Tools -> `Keyboard Shortcuts Help`). The only way I've figured out to do this via the keyboard is the following:

1. Type command at console (don't hit Enter)
2. `Ctrl + U` (copy line up to cursor)
3. `Ctrl + 1` (switch to source)
4. `Ctrl + Y` (paste line)
5. `Ctrl + 2` (switch back to console)

**Question:** As you can see, this is not much of a shortcut. Any other hacks? Or better yet, is there a way to define RStudio keyboard shortcuts in addition to the ones that are already defined?

**Environment:**
RStudio version 1.0.44
R version 3.3.2
Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: On Windows you could perhaps use `Auto-Hotkey` for automating your steps 2-5 (with up-arrow replacing the literal typing in step 1?). There does seem to be some Mac tools which correspond to Auto-HotKey such as: http://ahkscript.org/ . Not having a Mac, I don't know if this would be useful or worth it for you.

Comment: I know this is 6 years old but since there are no answers we can continue moving on the same thread. What is the browser you had used when you posted the question if you remember? Was any solution found?